# Android oAuth getting 'Received authentication challenge is null'

Tags: android, oauth

I am trying to connect to a site using the oAuth protocol, and I am getting the exception 'Received authentication challenge is null' on some devices when I attempt to make a https post.  Now this was previously working in the emulator, but I now see the error there as well.  I did a web search, and it seems like I would get this exception when I receive an 401 error from the site.  Others said this was due to a malformed authentication header, but I am not setting a authentication header at all for this call.

This exact same code works on a number of devices, and used to work in the emulator (I cannot figure out what has changed).  The person who runs the site has checked his logs, and does not see an error on his side at all. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.  It turns out that if the time stamp on your oAuth call is incorrect, the server returns a 401 status error which on Android devices causes the "Received authentication challenge is null" exception to be thrown.  All of the devices that were having this problem had incorrect times, and fixing the times fixed the problem.

Comment: Incorrect time's compared to what tho? What if my phone clock is 1 minute out, surely it shouldn't be so aggressive.